# Interpreting the output of a ScaledYOLOv4 ONNX model with ML.Net

Tags: c#, yolo, ml.net, onnx

I'm trying to consume a trained ScaledYOLOv4 model with ML.Net by following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/object-detection-onnx).

Here is the model I am working with: [image: Here is the model I am working with]
And here is the configuration file I used to train the model:

```yaml
# parameters
nc: 6  # number of classes
depth_multiple: 1.0  # model depth multiple
width_multiple: 1.0  # layer channel multiple

# anchors
anchors:
  - [12,16, 19,36, 40,28]  # P3/8
  - [36,75, 76,55, 72,146]  # P4/16
  - [142,110, 192,243, 459,401]  # P5/32

# yolov4-csp backbone
backbone:
  # [from, number, module, args]
  [[-1, 1, Conv, [32, 3, 1]],  # 0
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 2]],  # 1-P1/2
   [-1, 1, Bottleneck, [64]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 2]],  # 3-P2/4
   [-1, 2, BottleneckCSP, [128]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 2]],  # 5-P3/8
   [-1, 8, BottleneckCSP, [256]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 2]],  # 7-P4/16
   [-1, 8, BottleneckCSP, [512]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [1024, 3, 2]], # 9-P5/32
   [-1, 4, BottleneckCSP, [1024]],  # 10
  ]

# yolov4-csp head
# na = len(anchors[0])
head:
  [[-1, 1, SPPCSP, [512]], # 11
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [8, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]], # route backbone P4
   [[-1, -2], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 2, BottleneckCSP2, [256]], # 16 
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [6, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]], # route backbone P3
   [[-1, -2], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 2, BottleneckCSP2, [128]], # 21
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, 16], 1, Concat, [1]],  # cat
   [-1, 2, BottleneckCSP2, [256]], # 25
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, 11], 1, Concat, [1]],  # cat
   [-1, 2, BottleneckCSP2, [512]], # 29
   [-1, 1, Conv, [1024, 3, 1]],

   [[22,26,30], 1, Detect, [nc, anchors]],   # Detect(P3, P4, P5)
  ]
```

By using the code below, I've managed to have ONNX score an input image, though I am unsure if I did the preprocessing right.

```cs
var pipeline = MLContext.Transforms
  .LoadImages(
    outputColumnName: "images",
    imageFolder: String.Empty,
    inputColumnName: nameof(ImageNetData.ImagePath))

  .Append(MLContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(
    outputColumnName: "images",
    imageWidth: 896,
    imageHeight: 896,
    inputColumnName: "images"))

  .Append(MLContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(
    outputColumnName: "images"))

  .Append(MLContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(
    modelFile: ModelPath,
    outputColumnNames: new[] { "output" },
    inputColumnNames: new[] { "images" }));
```

After running it, it gave me an array of length 543312, which I assume stood for 1 * 49392 * 11. I got stuck after getting this array since I don't know where to look for the values ML.Net's guide used (row_count, column_count, channel_count, etc.) or if these even applies to my model. How should I go about postprocessing this array?